# Varchar 'YYMMDD' to Date 'DD.MM.YYYY'

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I want to convert a varchar '190613' in a date format 'DD.MM.YY'
The main problem is that the varchar is 'YY.MM.DD'

Comment: Hello! Can you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: `'190613'` does not appear to be in `'YY.MM.DD'` format. Also, transforming `'190613'` to `'130619'`can be done without caring about dates.

Answer (score 2):

You can do convert to a date and back to a string:

```
select to_char(to_date('190613', 'DDMMYY'), 'YY.MM.DD')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below:-

`select to_char(to_date('190613', 'DDMMYY'), 'YY.MM.DD') as dates from dual;`

Answer (score 0):

Your starting value is '190613', and you want to convert it to 'DD.MM.YY' format.

You should use as - Gordon stated

```
to_char(to_date('190613','YYMMDD'),'DD.MM.YY')
```

You also specified you have a starting template which is "YY.MM.DD". In that case, you need to specify dots in the to_date function

```
to_char(to_date('19.06.13','YY.MM.DD'),'DD.MM.YY')
```

to_date function serves to convert the varchar to a date sql type, you provide the starting template as second argument of the function to define which pattern your string follows. More info:
[to_date() SQL function](https://www.1keydata.com/sql/to_date.html)

Whilst to_char takes a date object and converts it to a specific template. More info: [to_char SQL function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the next form:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;  

String strDate = "190613"

DateTime dtDate= DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "mmddyy", provider);
```

if you want in especific format :

```
String.Format("{0:DD.MM.YY}",dtDate) // print  "19.06.13"
```

Comment: That is not Oracle - it is even not SQL